# send custom type to wcf service

Tags: c#, wcf

i need to pass an unknown type from my client to a wcf service ,

the type is unknown to the service .

for instance i have a class Customer which i create an instance of serialize and send to the service , the problem arises when i need to deserialize i have to provide the type in order to cast the desrialized object to .

Type can't be serialized , when attempted i get the following error :

```
{"Type 'System.RuntimeType' with data contract name 
 'RuntimeType:http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/System' is not expected. Consider 
  using a DataContractResolver or add any types not known statically to the list of 
  known types - for example, by using the KnownTypeAttribute attribute or by adding 
  them to the list of known types passed to DataContractSerializer."}
```

i need to find a work around for this issue , any ideas ?

just to summarize  :

i'm looking for a workaround for sending an unknown Type to a WCF service .

Comment: Can you clarify: does the "other end" have a: the same Customer class, but doesn't know in advance that the incoming data is a Customer instance, b: a different but similar/compatible Customer class, c: doesn't know anything about Customer?

Comment: How are you going to use the object once you receive it?

Comment: @MarcGravell c  - doesn't know any thing about the customer class

Comment: @eranotzer what is the purpose of this? Why do you need to pass an object which the receiving side doesn't know anything about? If you tell us more about your scenario, we may come up with better and more concrete suggestions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the other end doesn't know anything about it (comments), then you can't possibly deserialize. You couldn't do that even with Type-based serializers (BinaryFormatter/NetDataContractSerializer).

If you are sending completely foreign data, then you are basically limited to things like XML or JSON, and even then the meaning is slightly ambiguous (is `<id>123<id>` a string? int? float? long?).

WCF is not well suited to your scenario (nor most other contract-based stacks; most systems expect to be able to understand incoming data).

Comment: could it be possible to send an entire dll containing my Customer type
and then load it on the service side ?

Comment: I wouldn't say WCF is not suited. SOAP may not be, but a RESTful WCF web service, operating JSON or XML, will do fine.

Comment: i need to create a dynamic type process unit ,
which resolves around a specific object type which is send to the service .
i need to type in order to resolve the executing method of the type